# How can I Check the current value which is already passed or not in an array in nested foreach in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach

My array

```
$key1=>
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 7
    [3] => 11
    [4] => 12
    [5] => 17
    [6] => 18
)

$_POST['name']=>
Array
(
    [0] => General
    [1] => General
    [2] => Outdoors
    [3] => Dining
    [4] => Kitchen

)
```

Here is my code,

```
       foreach ($key1 as $key => $value) {
        // echo $value;
              foreach ($_POST['name'] as $key => $value1) {
                    //echo $value;
                    $subQueryCond .=' AND '.$value1.' LIKE  ' .$value ;
                         }
        }
```

While my Ajax calls this nested loop occurs..
Inside this I wrote a query..
If one value is passed.

The query is in the format of  `AND 'General' LIKE 1`.

And if another value is passed in the `$key1` it pass the query two times.

It's like How many arrays are given that much time that query was passed..

So,here I would like to restrict the `$value` if it already came..

if two values were given,it pass the query in the following manner

```
AND General LIKE  1 

AND Outdoors LIKE  1 

AND General LIKE  7 

AND Outdoors LIKE  7
```

And my desired query must be in the form of

```
AND General LIKE  1 

AND General LIKE  7 

AND Outdoors LIKE  7
```

can someone help me..

Comment: It's not clear to me what input should lead to what output, can you give some examples?

Comment: i think its `AND General LIKE  2`

Comment: Basically she needs unique values from $key1 array if i am not wrong. As you can see in her example output, `General` is repeated but not number after `LIKE`

Comment: As Zeeshan Hyder says I need the unique values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for you...

```
<?php 

$subQueryCond= '';
foreach ($key1 as $key => $value)
{
  foreach ($_POST['name'] as $key => $value1) 
  {
     $subQueryCond['AND '.$value1.' LIKE  ' .$value] = ' AND '.$value1.' LIKE  ' .$value ;
  }
}
echo "<pre>"; print_r($subQueryCond);
$query =  implode('',$subQueryCond) ;
print_r($query);

?>
```

just make an array with unique keys to value, then use implode() function to make query string...

Comment: Thank you so much @Manjeet Barnala..But I have a doubt in queries.. That how could I write query for ` LIKE '%$value%'' ` in the following format  `AND '.$value1.' LIKE  ' .$value`

Comment: replace this line  `$subQueryCond['AND '.$value1.' LIKE  ' .$value] = ' AND '.$value1.' LIKE  "%'.$value.'%"' ;`

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to remove duplicates from an array:

```
$uniqueKey1 = array_unique($key1);
```

And then you regular code:

```
 foreach ($uniqueKey1 as $key => $value) {
    // echo $value;
          foreach ($_POST['name'] as $key => $value1) {
                //echo $value;
                $subQueryCond .=' AND '.$value1.' LIKE  ' .$value ;
                     }
    }
```